# Importing a one line CSV in to a multi row datagridview

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I can import a CSV file into a datagridview as long as the "," match the columns and each new line in the csv equals a new row. My issue is, I have a file I'm converting into a CSV but it's one line long.
https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/cad.api

I'm completely at a loss.

I've already tried some basic code I use for my other programs.

```
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("\test.csv")
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
    Next
```

Each new row should start with something like.
(2006 QQ23)

Comment: since it looks like each row should contain 10 fields, you could break your `line.Split(",")` in chunks of 10 ? Or even Split on `[` which look like it would give you the records you want, then Split each of those records on `,` ?

Comment: it's a json not a csv.

Comment: Thanks Blaze, I'll give that a try.
Alessandro, ya I'm very unfamiliar with json. I've done some research but haven't figured out how to call the instances.

Comment: I figured it out with help from @blaze_125 thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get what I needed:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DownLoadFileInBackground2("https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/cad.api")
        LoadRaw()

    End Sub

    Public Sub DownLoadFileInBackground2(ByVal address As String)
        Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(address)
        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Try
            Dim mywebclient As New System.Net.WebClient()
            AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc_downloadComplete
            mywebclient.DownloadFile(uri, "neo.raw")
        Catch

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub wc_downloadComplete()

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadRaw()
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("neo.raw")
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains("[[") Then
            Dim dogIndex As Integer = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("[[")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(dogIndex, TextBox1.Text.Length - dogIndex)
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "],[", vbNewLine)
        TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "[", "")
        TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, """", "")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("conv.raw", TextBox1.Text, False)
        For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("conv.raw")
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```